# Stack input streams and stagger in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 input videos I want to stack vertically. I want the 3rd to play immediately and have the second start when the 3rd finishes. The command I currently have working is below:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i test2.mp4 -i test3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=320:240[top];[1:v]scale=320:240[mid];[2]scale=320:240[bot];[top][mid][bot]vstack=inputs=3[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -t 60 out.mp4
```

This works, but all 3 start immediately and only the audio from clip #2 is mapped. I'd like to tell ffmpeg to copy both audio streams but stagger the clips so that clip 3 plays, then clip 2 plays, both with their respective audio. Is this something that ffmpeg filters can do?

Comment: Clip 1 starts immediately?

Comment: Yes. Imagine clip 1 is just an intro overlay, and clip 2 is an actual user video.